# On can I open Fragments from Bottom Bar click listeners?

Tags: java, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I have created a bottombar with xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_signals"
        icon="@drawable/ic_recents"
        title="Signals"
        barColorWhenSelected="@color/colorAccent" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_tutorials"
        icon="@drawable/ic_favorites"
        title="Tutorials"
        barColorWhenSelected="#5D4037" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_training"
        icon="@drawable/ic_nearby"
        title="Training"
        barColorWhenSelected="#7B1FA2" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_management"
        icon="@drawable/ic_friends"
        title="Management"
        barColorWhenSelected="#FF5252" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_pool"
        icon="@drawable/ic_restaurants"
        title="Pool"
        barColorWhenSelected="#FF9800" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_contact"
        icon="@drawable/ic_restaurants"
        title="Contact"
        barColorWhenSelected="#FF9800" />
</tabs>
```

And my activity_main.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hi mom!" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs_color_changing"
        app:bb_behavior="shifting|underNavbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView messageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageView);

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                messageView.setText(TabClicks.get(tabId, false));
            }
        });

        bottomBar.setOnTabReselectListener(new OnTabReselectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TabClicks.get(tabId, true), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    
}
```

And another TabClicks.java which has click listeners as follows:

```
package com.example.bottombar.sample;

public class TabClicks {
    public static String get(int menuItemId, boolean isReselection) {
        String message = "Content for ";

        switch (menuItemId) {
            case R.id.tab_signals:
                message += "signals";
                break;
            case R.id.tab_tutorials:
                message += "tutorials";
                break;
            case R.id.tab_training:
                message += "training";
                break;
            case R.id.tab_management:
                message += "management";
                break;
            case R.id.tab_pool:
                message += "pool";
                break;
            case R.id.tab_contact:
                message += "contact";
                break;
        }

        if (isReselection) {
            message += " WAS RESELECTED! YAY!";
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly well, but now I want to change from displaying text to open Fragments. I want each item to open a fragment, how do I get started, how can i change this code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to open/replace fragments

```
Fragment someFragment = new SomeFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
transaction.commit();
```

However, from Material design guidelines a [bottom navigation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#usage) should have 3-5 items. Yours has 6 which I would suggest you use a navigation drawer.

You can also check out bottom navigation with the [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) which makes the navigation and replacing of fragments a lot more easier.